# How to add value to a form group using add control

Tags: angular, typescript

How do we add controls to a formgroup ? I tried the ff below but it does not add. Any idea? thanks.

```
modelForm: FormGroup;

//this happens on ngOnit
this.modelForm = this._createModelForm();

private _createModelForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [this.model.id || 0],
      summary: this.model.summary,
      dealType: this.model.dealType,
      dealTypeValues: this.model.dealTypeValues,
    });

  }
```

For example I want to add

`this.modelForm.addControl('dealType',new FormControl('Partner Location Submission'));`

but does not seem to work, any idea guys? thank you.

Comment: There is already a form control named 'dealType' in your form group. and the addControl() statement you are using is referring to the same control.

Comment: If you need multiple instances of a set of controls, you can use a FormArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing form incorrectly. If you open browser console you gonna see error `Error: this.validator is not a function`. You should initialize fields with `FormControl`

```
return this.formBuilder.group({
  id: new FormControl([this.model.id || 0]),
  summary: new FormControl(this.model.summary),
  dealType: new FormControl(this.model.dealType),
  dealTypeValues: new FormControl(this.model.dealTypeValues),
});
```

**Optional**: I suggest initiating form with FormGroup function instead of formBuilder because the code will be treeshakable(smaller bundle size).

```
 return new FormGorup({
  id: new FormControl([this.model.id || 0]),
  summary: new FormControl(this.model.summary),
  dealType: new FormControl(this.model.dealType),
  dealTypeValues: new FormControl(this.model.dealTypeValues),
});
```